# Messed Up Permissions on Catalina

Tags: terminal, catalina, permission, filesystem

I am an on-and-off user of Sibelius, and the version I own turns out to be partially incompatible with Big Sur. Some months after upgrading to Big Sur, I decided that I wanted to use my version of Sibelius and have it work as intended. So I reinstalled Catalina. I figured I could migrate my Time Machine backup without issue, but Migration Assistant couldn't find it. So I dragged files I needed to my computer from my external drive manually. However, I found that there were permissions issues. For example, I tried editing a JS file in VS Code, and it wouldn't save, telling me it didn't have permission. It gave me the option to try with sudo, which I did, but that still didn't work. I've tried the following:

- Using the Finder to try to recursively apply permissions to my user to Macintosh HD's contents (was told by a popup that I didn't have permissions).
- diskutil disableOwnership on one of the volumes.
- chmod -R
- chown -R
- sudo diskutil resetUserPermissions / id -u (with backticks)
- Repairing permissions from the Terminal in Recovery Mode

Has anyone had an issue like this and found success with another option? I suppose that the reason I can't recursively apply permissions to the hard drive is that there are files within there that I don't have permissions for, even after clicking the little lock, but I'm at a loss with what to do after trying all of this stuff in the Terminal/Recovery Mode.

Comment: Can you show some concrete examples (with filenames) of Terminal commands and error messages?

Comment: I have mostly avoided error messages. The issue is that, though commands were executed, the issue is not fixed.

Comment: "So I reinstalled Catalina" How?  In particular, did you erase the whole system/boot disk before installing Catalina?

Comment: Applying recursive changes to the boot volume isn't a good idea -- there are a lot of system files that have to have specific ownership and permissions to work right. You really need to figure out which files have the wrong perms, what they should be, and fix just them; don't take a sledgehammer to the permissions system or you'll just make more problems.

Comment: I formatted the boot disk and started with Catalina from a clean slate. And yes, but unfortunately it for some reason didn't even want to let me fix permissions on just a few files. For example, even chmod 777 on a single file just to test it (I know you're not supposed to do that in general) didn't work...VS Code still couldn't write to the file.